# C++ вектора пара вопросов

Tags: c++

Начал активно использовать вектора, как замену обычным массивам, по совету людей отсюда. Есть пара вопросов.

1) Как считать в двумерный вектор строки разной длины.

2) Возможно ли делать двумерные вектора смешанного типа, например у меня пусть будет вектор имеющий 2 строки и 10 столбцов. 1я строка отвечает за тип данных bool, вторая строка отвечает за int? Или это маразм и надо использовать в таких случая структуры?

Comment: Из вашего описания не ясно, что вы хотите получить. Приведите более конкретные примеры.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow по первому примеру считать из файла строки как например в двумерный char массив через file.getline. по второму например у меня есть 10 стаканов - 10 столбцов. первая строка отвечает за bool - наполнен или нет вторая за int - ёмкость.

Comment: Вы строки хотите хранить, или отдельно символы строк?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow да отдельно символы строк std::vector<std::vector<char>>

Comment: Ну, и в чем проблема?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow у меня либо происходит переполнение либо у меня в строке с размером меньше чем у максимальной появляются символы из нижней строки и так далее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из вашего комментария к вашему же собственному вопросу можно заключить, что достаточно для первого примера объявить "одномерный" вектор строк. Например,

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
```

Или можно объявить "двумерный вектор" символов. Например,

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> v;

std::string s;

while ( std::getline( std::cin, s ) )
{
    // Можно  использовать любую из перечисленных конструкций
    v.push_back( std::vector<char>( s.begin(), s.end() ) );
    //v.push_back( { s.begin(), s.end() } );
    //v.emplace_back( s.begin(), s.end() );
}
```

Что касается второго вопроса, то вы можете либо объявить пару векторов, например,

```
std::pair<std::vector<bool>, std::vector<int>> v;
```

Или вектор пар. Например.

```
std::vector<std::pair<bool, int>> v;
```

С другой стороны, так как размер фиксирован и не велик, то можно просто объявить объект

```
std::array<std::pair<bool, int>, 10> a;
```

Comment: Более универсально, наверное, `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

1) как у вас двумерные вектора устроены? `std::vector<std::string>` без вопросов может хранить строки разной длины.
2) Если вам нужно ассоциировать bool и int делайте соответствующую структуру и храните уже ее в векторах.